# Can I use inetd or xinetd as a web server?

Tags: shell-script, shell, xinetd, inetd

I just want to know if it is possible to use `xinetd` as a web server to server simple piped commands.

For example, I want the output of `ps -ef|grep root|wc -l` to be served over HTTP using `xinetd` (without any other server software). How can I do that?

Comment: I would use grep -c instead of piping to wc -l

Comment: You should be able to as per https://github.com/rglaue/xinetd_bash_http_service